# Express Serving files from different location on https

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-ec2, angular-fullstack

I am running an app that is loosely based off the angular-fullstack app. It has both an http server and an https server with the same express app. My app runs fine on my local machine, in http or https, even when I run `NODE_ENV="production" node server/app.js`. However, when I push the dist folder to my AWS ec2 instance, the app works only for `http://example.com`, not https.

At the https address, I get `Error: ENOENT, stat 'client/index.html' at Error (native)`. I do not have a client folder, my client code such as index.html is in a folder named public. I do not understand why this content is served correctly in http but not https and would grateful if someone could help me out.

```
//Server/app.js file
var app = express();

var httpsServer = require('https').createServer(credentials, app);
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpsServer.listen(httpsPort, config.ip, function () {
  console.log('https Express server listening on %d, in %s mode', httpsPort, app.get('env'));
});
httpServer.listen(httpPort, config.ip, function () {
  console.log('http Express server listening on %d, in %s mode', httpPort, app.get('env'));
});



var env = app.get('env');
app.set('views', config.root + '/server/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.use(compression());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(passport.initialize());
console.log(env)
if ('production' === env) {
  app.use(favicon(path.join(config.root, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
  console.log(path.join(config.root, 'public'));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, 'public')));
  app.set('appPath', config.root + '/public');
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
}

if ('development' === env || 'test' === env) {
  console.log('i am overwriting everything');
  app.use(require('connect-livereload')());
  app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, '.tmp')));
  app.use(express.static(path.join(config.root, 'client')));
  app.set('appPath', 'client');
  app.use(morgan('dev'));
  app.use(errorHandler()); 
}
```

`env` logs as `'production'`. 
`path.join(config.root, 'public')` logs to `/home/ubuntu/www/public/`
`I am overwriting everything` never logs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be running your development.js after you push into the server. In order to keep it from reading your development, try adding a start script in your package.json.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV="production" node server/app.js"
}
```